# In Visual Studio 2019, What Command is Run When 'Test All' is Clicked?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, test-explorer, dotnet-test

Visual Studio 2019 (and most Visual Studios that I've worked with that have a Test Explorer) have a 'Test All' button.

[image]

I'm curious as to what the CLI-equivalent [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) is run when this is clicked (including all options fed to this command). For example, `dotnet test ...`. I'm sure the `--no-build` option is **not** specified, as clicking this button runs a build. Does anyone know what the entire command that is run is?

Comment: If you want to run multiple projects with one command maybe you can try this method(https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/705#issuecomment-294316587).

Comment: I doubt that Visual Studio runs `dotnet test`. Probably it uses some dedicated test APIs and executes the tests directly

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to replicate the function of the Test Explorer at the command line then for Visual Studio on Windows, "*VSTest.Console.exe* is the command-line tool to run tests." Within [Testing tools in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/?view=vs-2022), see [Run tests from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2022).

The IDE, however, is not spawning new vstest.console processes on every test run. It is 're-using' existing test runner instances via an API/protocol.